# Python split data from arduino serial to raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi

i have an output from serial arduino like this on raspberry

```
30.27|34.00\n
30.27|32.00\n
30.21|33.00\n
```

code on raspberry:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
while 1 :
    ser.readline()
```

i want to spit like this

```
x=30.21
y=33.00
```

is this possible if data send in real time,

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same code you already have, try:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
while 1 :
    data=ser.readline()
    x=data.split("|")[0]
    y=data.split("|")[1]
    print "x=",x
    print "y=",y
```

You can streamline the code some more but wanted to make it step by step for easier reading.

Comment: Streamline like: x,y =data.split('|')